# I'm having trouble installing packaged in R on Windows, getting Error 127

Tags: r, windows, installation

I've got R installed on my windows machine (new machine at work so preinstalled by the technician), and I am unable to install any packages. For example one error that I keep getting is:

```
install.packages("tibble")
```

gives the error:

```
*** arch - i386
C:/Program Files/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG              -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c assumptions.c -o assumptions.o
sh: C:/Program: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: assumptions.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'fansi'
* removing 'C:/Users/pweller/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/fansi'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fansi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'fansi' is not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/pweller/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'fansi', 'pillar' are not available for package 'tibble'
* removing 'C:/Users/pweller/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/tibble'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? It seems to begin with the installation ofthe `fansi` package and the `Error 127`.

My R version:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try reinstalling Rtools : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: @BastienDucreux thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I'm still getting the errors though...

Comment: @BastienDucreux I did a fresh install and now it works. It seems that it did have something to do with Rtools in the path as before the package was searching for "C:/rtools40/ming_w64/bin/" which didn't exist, but now it searches for "C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/" which is correct. Not sure generally what was happening though.

Comment: I would also update R if possible. Your version is a couple of years old now.